# How to run Solr Jetty in background

Tags: java, solr, terminal, jetty

I am using the Jetty/Solr build that comes with Solr and would like to run it in the background instead of in the terminal.

Right now  I start it by `java -jar start.jar` but I would like it to log to a file and run in the background on the server so that I can close the terminal window.

I'm sure there is some java config that I can't find.

I have tried `java -jar start.jar > log.txt &` but no luck still outputs to the terminal window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try something like:

```
nohup yourcommand > output.log 2>&1 &
```

**nohup** will prevent yourcommand from being terminated in the event you log out.

**&** will run it in the background.

**> output.log** will send stdout to output.log

[2>&1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-bash-shell-what-is-21) will redirect stderr to stdout

Comment: How can start Jetty server every time I reboot?

Comment: // , @sokratis, I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/19240843/2146138 might answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

nohup is used to execute commands that runs after logout from a shell. What you need here is '2>&1'. This redirects standart error to the standart output. So everything will be logged to log.txt.
Try this

> java -jar start.jar > log.txt 2>&1

Also you can add an '&' start it as a background process.

Answer (score 3):

You can run it with `screen` if you are on unix.

Answer (score 3):

You can properly install it as a linux service too.

cd to your jetty folder, for example mine is:

```
cd /home/spydon/jetty/
```

They have actually made most of the work with the jetty.sh file, so copy that one to /etc/init.d/

```
sudo cp ./bin/jetty.sh /etc/init.d/jetty
```

Then open the file with your favorite text editor, like vim or nano

```
sudo vim /etc/init.d/jetty
```

In the beginning simply uncomment (remove the hash(#)) three lines that says something like:

```
 #chkconfig: 3 99 99
 #description: Jetty 9 webserver
 #processname: jetty
```

Meanwhile you have the text editor open, also add the jetty home directory to the beginning of the file, mine now looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash  
#
# Startup script for jetty under *nix systems (it works under NT/cygwin too).
JETTY_HOME=/home/spydon/jetty

# To get the service to restart correctly on reboot, uncomment below (3 lines):
# ========================
 chkconfig: 3 99 99
 description: Jetty 9 webserver
 processname: jetty
# ========================
```

Now you should be able to start it with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/jetty start
```

And if you want it to run every time you reboot, simply add

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/jetty /etc/rc1.d/K99jetty
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/jetty /etc/rc2.d/S99jetty
```

This should work for most modern distros, but I've only tried it on debian based ones.
You could also consider doing a symlink to the jetty.sh so it will be easier to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try `nohup`, as explained in this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534648/how-to-daemonize-a-java-program/534756#534756).