# How to run Apache-Solr server as background process?

Tags: java, apache, solr, indexing, background-process

I am using **Apache-Solr** for indexing and searching in my java application. 
If want to perform any operation related to Apache-Solr then the **solr server** is must to be started.

Sometime the terminal in which Solr-server is running is closed accidentally then we have to start that server again, because we can not perform any Search/Index related operation.

I tried to run process in background by putting '**&**' at end of the command, but it does not working.

I do not want to that terminal is opened in which server is running. So is there any way to run the Apache-Solr-Server in background process?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: // , My brother had the same question about the Cowboy server. Should he ask a separate question, or can he use the answers on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this link will be useful for you it  talks about how to use screen if you are using linux  and other stuff

[start apache-solr-server in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287561/how-to-run-solr-jetty-in-background)

also you may  start 
Solr automatically by creating an init/LaunchDaemon script and let the 
system handle running it.