# How to automatically launch a Gradle based Java application/daemon on startup in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, bash, amazon-ec2, gradle

I have a Gradle based Java application. The app is actually a daemon. On my local box, I can start the daemon by running:

```
> gradle run
```

That works great, but what I need is a way to kick off the daemon when the host is rebooted. I'm trying to get this to work on an EC2 instance.

Comment: Isn't this largely equivalent to "how do I run an arbitrary command on startup?".

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19634/linux-equivalent-for-windows-startup.

Comment: Can you clarify - you are using gradle to run the application in production and not just to build it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a plugin to do just this. The primary components are to generate init.d scripts, another component is to package them into a DEB or RPM. I haven't tied it with the application plugin itself just yet, but it's close, it's called the nebula-ospackage-daemon plugin: https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-ospackage-plugin#nebula-ospackage-daemon. You would do something like:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories { jcenter() }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.netflix.nebula:nebula-ospackage-plugin:1.12.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "sample.Main"

apply plugin: 'os-package'
apply plugin: 'nebula-ospackage-daemon'

daemon {
    command = "/opt/myapp/bin/ospackage-application"
}

ospackage {
    into('/opt/myapp')
    with(applicationDistribution)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar.

Perhaps you may want to look at the [following Gradle plugin](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-java-distribution) that is similar to Gradle application plugin but also installs app as init.d service.

A different solution (simple script) is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203483/run-a-java-application-as-a-service-on-linux).