# JAVA - Raspberry-pi - Application as a service who start then stop immediately

Tags: java, service, raspberry-pi2

I need to start a Java app on raspberry's startup,
but i can't figure how?!

- I've retreive the PbxMan's script to run it as a service : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21283530/5066919
- I've made a simple script that launch the app in background
- I've pushed it in a crontab at reboot...

I play a sound on the first line of the main and in the addShutdownHook().
So i can hear that each time, the app start then stop immediately...

Of course i don't have this problem when I launch it in CLI! :@

Comment: some news? i'm turning it in differents ways but can't solve it... Ask me if you need some more info?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved,

I post what i've found if some one have the same ;)

My app run a Thread, waiting for keyboards entries to run live tests and shutdown app when this loop is break with 'q',

```
while( scanner.hasNext() ){
  ...
}
```

"This method may block while waiting for input to scan" say the JavaDoc, ... may block...

In a case of a service, or when you put the app in background, "has next" don't block, so my app thinks 'q' was send and shutdown.

I've just added a starting parameter to use app asService or not, which disable or not this waiting loop..!

That's all folk!