# Spring Boot + Gradle: how to build executable jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm trying to build an executable jar in Spring Boot + Gradle project, but for now nothing works. Here is the simplest possible structure. Possibly, something is missing in Gradle configuration.

Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.demo.DemoApplication'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
}
```

Main config file:

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

[image]

When I ran the jar file like java -jar 1.jar, I got this exception:

```
[main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Applicati
on startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to proces
s import candidates for configuration class [com.example.demo.DemoApplication];
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration cl
asses found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, m
ake sure that file is correct.
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.proce
ssDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:556)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse
(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcesso
r.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcesso
r.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate
.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.ja
va:272)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate
.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invoke
BeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
xt.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.
java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringAppli
cation.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
:1107)
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes fou
nd in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure
that file is correct.
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:277)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelecto
r.getCandidateConfigurations(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:153)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelecto
r.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:95)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.proce
ssDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:547)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I created a project with all the sources you provided. Running "gradle build" from terminal, switching to /build/libs and then running "java -jar artifactname" works just fine.

Have you tried to clean and recompile? Which Version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: I didn't know I had to use 'gradle build' and was trying 'gradle jar' instead. Now it works

Comment: how to provide spring profile with gradle build command

Answer (score 44):

In Boot 2.x, the bootJar and bootWar tasks are responsible for packaging the application.

The bootJar task is responsible for creating the executable jar file. This is created automatically once the java plugin is applied.

In case the executable jar/war file is not generated run the below gradle task manually.

```
$./gradlew bootJar
```

Similarly, bootWar generates an executable war file and gets created once the war plugin is applied.

We can execute the bootWar task using:

```
$./gradlew bootWar
```

Note that for Spring Boot 2.x, we need to use Gradle 4.0 or later.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. i was trying out with 5.6.4(Oracle JDK 1.8) along with Lombok; and adding spring boot {} was creating an issue..But specifying bootJar  is working.

Comment: Can you brief me about the command you are using to launch the jar file

Comment: [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#building-executable-jars-and-wars)

Answer (score 11):

In spring boot you can directly create executable jar file by

```
springBoot { 
    executable = true 
}
```

Please try

```
jar{
    baseName = 'myapp' 
    version = 'version'
}
```

It will create jar with name myapp-version.jar
Do ./myapp-version.jar from command line.it will execute

Refer following link for more info. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

Comment: `executable` is outdated.
`Could not set unknown property 'executable' for extension 'springBoot' of type org.springframework.boot.gradle.dsl.SpringBootExtension.`

Answer (score 6):

I just recently tried a Spring boot application with 2.1.4.Release with Gradle build.

I ran the following command from the  directory in Windows CMD.

```
gradlew clean build
```

(upon required JDK8 installed in the system), I was able to see the JAR generated under,

```
<project-directory>/build/libs/<project-name-version.jar>
```

Hope this helps though older question.

Reference:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to make your .jar file executable, for use such as in a systemd service. You'll have to edit the `bootJar` task and enable `launchScript`.

`build.gradle`

```
bootJar {
    launchScript()
}
```

or with Gradle Kotlin DSL `build.gradle.kts`

```
tasks {
    bootJar {
        launchScript()
    }
}
```

You should now be able to run your project's .jar file as an executable.

Answer (score 2):

My two cents.

When using spring-boot if you want to customize the `MANIFEST.MF` file, you need to set the `bootJar` task, it won't work on the default `jar` task.

```
bootJar {
    manifest {
    attributes 'Start-Class': 'com.baeldung.DemoApplication'
    }
}
```

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-main-class

Answer (score 1):

For me clicking on "jar" under gradle tasks in intellij created jar under./build/libs/

[image: Click jar not bootJar]