# I cannnot run CommandLineJobRunner in dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, spring-batch

I run the following code. But output error.

> (Docker file)
> From openjdk
> COPY ./* /tmp
> WORKDIR /tmp
> ENV CLASSPATH=target/spring_batch_commandline_sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:lib/*:target/classes/*
> CMD java org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner -next job-setting.xml job1

Files:

[image: Files]

Error running container after building image

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner

I could run the files on Windows powershell and wsl.

(powershell)

```
java -cp 'target/spring_batch_commandline_sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;lib/*' org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner -next job-setting.xml job1
```

(wsl)

```
java -cp 'target/spring_batch_commandline_sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:lib/*' org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner -next job-setting.xml job1
```

I can not understand the reason for this error.
Please answer it.

Comment: Check which files were copied - were they done recursively and completely? Check whether `$CLASSPATH` is what you think it is

Comment: unless you have to, would strongly recommend the single jar spring-boot produces: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started.first-application.executable-jar for maven and https://stackoverflow.com/a/52404325/995891 for gradle and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-console-app for an example regarding commandlinerunner. You only need the `spring-boot-starter` (without the usual `-something` suffix) to have a single jar that contains all the libraries and would need nothing but `java -jar myjar.jar -next job-setting.xml job1` to run

Answer (score 1):

Try to surround the value of CLASSPATH with "", meaning:

```
ENV CLASSPATH="..."
```

Also try to explicitly add the classpath to your command:

```
CMD java -cp $CLASSPATH ...
```

That said, I would recommend shading your jar and use a command like:

```
java -jar mybachjob.jar
```

Spring Boot does that for you, otherwise you can use [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).