# Cannot start systemd service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, spring-boot

I have a spring boot executable jar in a digital ocean droplet. I'm able to execute the jar using  `java -jar myapp.jar` Now I want to have i run as a service.

I've created the file **/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service** with these contents

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=kevin
ExecStart=/var/myapp/myapp-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enabled it to start at system startup

```
systemctl enable myapp.service
```

I'm now attempting to start the service

```
systemctl start myapp.service
```

But I'm getting this error

> Failed to start myapp.service: Unknown unit: myapp.service
>   See system logs and 'systemctl status myapp.service' for details.

running `systemctl status myapp.service` return this:

```
Failed to get properties: No such interface ''
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=kevin
ExecStart=java -jar /var/myapp/myapp-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have add :

**java -jar** in youre ExecStart

**Restart=always** => If java crack, systemd restart the service

**RestartSec=5** => After crash the service restart avec 5 seconds

After youre modification, reload the systemd daemon :

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Enable on startup :

```
systemctl enable myapp.service
```

And start now :

```
systemctl start myapp.service
```

Comment: Still getiing this error:

Failed to start myapp.service: Unknown unit: myapp.service
See system logs and 'systemctl status myapp.service' for details.

Comment: Can you join the output of "systemctl -xn" after systemctl restart myapp.service ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a wrapper script for the jar mentioned in `ExecStart` to handle start, stop and restart methods.

Extensive instructions and an example script can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203483/run-a-java-application-as-a-service-on-linux/21283530#21283530)