# Registration service spring-boot-maven-plugin can't stop

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I registered the application as a Linux service in the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and started it using a `./app.jar start`, The problem is that you can't stop after you start.

- Registration service configuration

  org.springframework.boot
  spring-boot-maven-plugin

      true
- Start command

  nohup /data/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar start --spring.profiles.active=test  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
- End command

  nohup /data/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar start --spring.profiles.active=stop  > /dev/null 2>&1 &

Here I use the stop command to stop the application I started earlier, but the application started again and an error was reported: `java.net.BindException: Address already in use`

I don't know how to solve this problem, see in the document about the registration for the service of practice is to use the Sys V and Systemd but I don't have any server Root can't use these two tools - -

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:990)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:635)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1022)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:250)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:193)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.airspace.airfence.ElectronicFenceApplication.main(ElectronicFenceApplication.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
2018-06-21T19:38:13.371 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.log[181] - Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9280]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9280]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:250)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:193)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.airspace.airfence.ElectronicFenceApplication.main(ElectronicFenceApplication.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:990)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:635)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1022)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

I'm really sorry, my English is not very good
Please understand if the wording is inaccurate in terms of tone

Comment: Check your "end command". It says "start" you are only passing the active profile as stop.

Comment: Both the commands are actually starting the app with different active profile. I guess you need to change your end command.

Comment: @narayan-sambireddy I do not know how to write this configuration file, where to write application.properties or pom.xml

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203483/run-a-java-application-as-a-service-on-linux