# How can i run a java program as a daemon using JNA/JNI without nohup/wrappers

Tags: java, java-native-interface, daemon, jna

I am trying to start a program using "java -jar $filename" and have it fork itself and keep running in the background, like it is possible with other programming languages e.g. in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9047339)

Comment: ["Is it possible?" as a question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/2463)

Comment: well fwiw i *am* trying to figure out if this is even possible

Comment: For windows -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113/how-to-create-a-windows-service-from-java-app For Linux https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203483/run-a-java-application-as-a-service-on-linux

Comment: looks like it still relies on jsvc? at least i am finding code samples that leverage jsvc + apache commons daemon

Comment: which means that java is not the entrypoint, jsvc is. i think the answer to my question is no....

Answer (score 0):

The library which accomplishes this is `org.kohsuke:akuma:1.10` on maven central