# How to run scheduled job in java spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, scheduler, jobs

I use

```
 CommandLineJobRunnerWrapper
```

as main class. For run job use

```
SimpleJobLauncher
```

for execute job one time. How I could schedule it to execute e.g. each day at 10 o'clock?
Because now application immedeately exit after method execute finished.
I have tried use spring scheduler but without success.

Comment: you can use spring task scheduler to schedule the jobs , it use the @schedule for any method with cron expression .

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the [Scheduled](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--) annotation

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 10 * * MON-FRI")
```

on your method.

Comment: yes, I have used but application don't remain up. It exits.

Comment: You will have to keep your application running ;-) Like `while(true){Thread.sleep(10000);}` after you initialized Spring or do something else to daemonize your application - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/534648/510711 for example.

Comment: Are you sure with that cron expression? Shouldn't it be `0 0 10 * * MON-FRI` (or `0 0 10 * * ?`)?