# Trigger Test case execution -Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, testng, ui-automation

I am looking for an approach to trigger automated test scripts with out relying on Jenkins, QC, Test Rail, MTM etc.To understand this in detail, let me  explain an example. As part of testing process, the manual tester would require to trigger a set of test cases for execution and he/she has no access to Eclipse IDE. The test cases are developed using selenium API -Java and he/she would simply have to trigger a set of test cases as part of regression. Is there an approach to it? I assume this can be achieved using windows task scheduler but I am looking for a best approach. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: [Daemonize the Test script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534648/how-to-daemonize-a-java-program) with [Java Scheduler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814089/how-to-schedule-a-periodic-task-in-java)

Comment: Your question is confusing. You stated _"I am looking for an approach to trigger automated test scripts with out relying on Jenkins, QC, Test Rail, MTM etc."_ and then _"and he/she would simply have to trigger a set of test cases"_. Do you want to schedule the tests or are they meant to be run _ad hoc_ by a user? If the former **Java Scheduler** is the way to go, if the latter consider packing your test suite into a **JAR** file, which the user can execute (also you might provide a **BAT** file for easy config if needed).