# Reading network directory with java using scheduled task

Tags: java, file, networking, scheduled-tasks

I have spent two days trying to get this to work. J: is a mapped network drive.

```
import java.io.File;

File file = new File("J:\\data\\newpasload\\savedir\\");
File[] attachedFiles=file.listFiles();
if (attachedFiles==null) {
    System.out.println("Failed to read j: drive");
} else {
    System.out.println("Number of files = "+attachedFiles.length);
}
```

The executable jar file works fine when run directly, showing me the number of files in the directory. However I want the executable jar file to run as a scheduled task. When I run it as such the attachedFiles becomes null.

Comment: Is the jar executed with different privileges from the scheduled job?

Comment: I don't think so but not sure how to find out. Have ticked Run with highest privileges. It's me running it both ways.

Answer (score 0):

According [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) listFiles() returns:

> An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in
>   the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be
>   empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract
>   pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs

So you should check path or task permissions. As a variant you can run your java application as a [daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534648/how-to-daemonize-a-java-program).