# daemon for solr

Tags: solr, daemon

I would like to run solr with daemon.  I saw in another post there is a init.d script you can run but it seems to have problems in my ubuntu environment.  whenever i try to run the script with /etc/init.d/solr start or when i try to run the below line manually:

```
daemon java -jar start.jar
```

it errors:

```
daemon: invalid option -- 'j'
```

Any ideas?  thx.

Answer (score 8):

Below is a working script for daemonizing Solr. Couple important notes here:

1. You need to set the chdir for the daemon script or else you'll get errors loading your config file.
2. This will allow you to start/stop/status/restart Solr.
3. This is a simple version that seems to be working for me.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Prerequisites:
# 1. Solr needs to be installed at /usr/local/solr/example
# 2. daemon needs to be installed
# 3. Script needs to be executed by root

# This script will launch Solr in a mode that will automatically respawn if it
# crashes. Output will be sent to /var/log/solr/solr.log. A pid file will be 
# created in the standard location.

start () {
    echo -n "Starting solr..."

    # start daemon
    daemon --chdir='/usr/local/solr/example' --command "java -jar start.jar" --respawn --output=/var/log/solr/solr.log --name=solr --verbose

    RETVAL=$?
    if [ $RETVAL = 0 ]
    then
        echo "done."
    else
        echo "failed. See error code for more information."
    fi
    return $RETVAL
}

stop () {
    # stop daemon
    echo -n "Stopping solr..."

    daemon --stop --name=solr  --verbose
    RETVAL=$?

    if [ $RETVAL = 0 ]
    then
        echo "done."
    else
        echo "failed. See error code for more information."
    fi
    return $RETVAL
}


restart () {
    daemon --restart --name=solr  --verbose
}


status () {
    # report on the status of the daemon
    daemon --running --verbose --name=solr
    return $?
}


case "$1" in
    start)
        start
    ;;
    status)
        status
    ;;
    stop)
        stop
    ;;
    restart)
        restart
    ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: solr {start|status|stop|restart}"
        exit 3
    ;;
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

Comment: does you know how can I install daemon on a CentOS box?

Comment: Also - Just wanted to point out I can run this as a non-root user with no problems. Just had to do CHOWN -R myuser on the DATA directory in the Solr directory

Comment: **daemon** does not come installed on some Debian system.  `sudo apt-get install daemon` should resolve such issues.

Answer (score 1):

See:

- [How to Daemonize a Java Program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534648/how-to-daemonize-a-java-program)
- [How to convert an existing Java application to a SYS V service (daemon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407016/how-to-convert-an-existing-java-application-to-a-sys-v-service-daemon)

Comment: unfortunatelly jetty does not implement the proper interface to be used with Apache Daemon (jsvc)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
daemon `java -jar start.jar`
```