# SolrCloud - Jetty vs Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, solr, jetty, solrcloud

We're looking to use SolrCloud with separate ZooKeeper instances but need some advice. Our situation is - multiple collections, each with multiple shard's running on Ubuntu 13, Solr 4.7.0, separate ZooKeeper 3.4.5, OpenJDK 7 in AWS

- Jetty or Tomcat? Jetty is built in and requires less config but unless specifying "nohup" the SolrCloud instance exits when you exit the java command running SolrCloud or when you disconnect the SSH session. In addition, it doesn't run as a service out of the box so there's extra config to get it to startup with the server.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed that Jetty is the right way to go, but ended up going with the below style solution:

[daemon for solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420127/daemon-for-solr)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Jetty. As this is what comes bundled, that is what use most commiters and all the testing suite, so it is generally recommended.

You can easily set it up as a service, I have used at least two methods in the past:

- using runit, as described [here](http://searchhub.org/2011/08/10/running-solr-as-a-service-on-linux/)
- using [yajsw](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/): this is what I use now, cross platform (so you can use it on windows too, for the odd installation that needs windows). It's an opensource implementation of the well known Java Service Wrapper.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestions. runit looks a little more simple but just so I understand the process, can you please confirm the below:

1) sudo apt-get install runit
2) mkdir /etc/solr/sv/solr
3) nano /etc/solr/sv/solr/run 
4) java -DzkHost="xxxx:2181" -jar start.jar
5) chmod a+x /etc/solr/sv/solr/run
6) runsv /etc/solr/sv/solr

That's it?

Comment: it is hard to confirm exactly those commands would work, maybe you need to tweak some paths etc (depending on linux version you are using), also you might need to run all as su (easy but not the right thing to do) or sudo whenever necessary and so forth. If you have some linux admin able to help would be a breeze, otherwise, trial&error will get you there eventually too.